# "Toutmai started the second officer's job at.." vs "Toutmai started a second officer's job at"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> In 2011, she joined the XYZ Institute as a navigation officer. After
>   over two years in the institute, in November 2013, Toutmai started the
>   second officer's job at Siren for Fleet Ship Management.
>
> In 2011, she joined the XYZ Institute as a navigation officer. After
>   over two years in the institute, in November 2013, Toutmai started a
>   second officer's job at Siren for Fleet Ship Management.

I know that we say "I am **a** teacher". I digged [deeper into articles](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/) and learned about another rule, that is, we use **the** before superlatives and ordinal numbers. In the quoted sentences these two rules seem to be in conflict. Should I use **a** because *second officer* is a job title, or should I use 
**the** because of the presence of the ordinal number? Or does it depend on a context?
I cannot imagine answering the question,

> Who is the second officer on this ship?

with "I am **a** second officer." Seems not specific enough. Please clarify.

Comment: [correction: I dug //after more than two years]

Comment: @Lambie: Why "more than" instead of "over"?

Comment: You should think of "**second officer**" as a single indivisible "job type identifier", along the lines of "**head waiter**" or "**bus driver**". The second officer on a ship is a complete job designation in and of itself. It's not really an "ordinal" usage such as might occur in *For long-distance overnight journeys, the company always sends **a second bus driver** out with each vehicle*.

Comment: It depends to some extent if there is one second officer on a ship, or several second officers. Is it a general thing like being a sales assistant or able seaman, or a particular position held by one person at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either is correct. I might say:

> Toutmai started as second officer at Siren

or, less literally

> Toutmai took the role of second officer at Siren